# What is exec transaction on etherscan?

Tags: transactions, wallets, etherscan, transfer, wallet-transfer

I'm looking at wallet address 0x28257E0Ae6aC7a31fbfB19aaF29A17122Af89B5c and I noticed transaction 0x40fa247fc9f6a3e4801ea9697f5be1e6a69af4c88dd8bcb5161c0c23a325a524 method is labelled as "exec transaction"? Over 500 eth were transferred.

Can someone explain to me what's the difference between exec transaction vs a regular transfer? And why does the value appear as 0 eth even though a substantial amount of eth was transferred?

Answer (score 1):

This is a function from a Gnosis Safe contract, a multi-sig wallet smart contract.
Here's the function description :

> /// @dev Allows to execute a Safe transaction confirmed by required
> number of owners and then pays the account that submitted the
> transaction.

If you want to check the function code, you can find it here [File 1 of 15 : GnosisSafe.sol, line 99](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd9db270c1b5e3bd161e8c8503c55ceabee709552#code#F1#L99)

If you don't know how I found it, here's the procedure :

In [your transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x40fa247fc9f6a3e4801ea9697f5be1e6a69af4c88dd8bcb5161c0c23a325a524), you can find the contract address  https://etherscan.io/address/0x28257e0ae6ac7a31fbfb19aaf29a17122af89b5c

Then, if you go to the "Contract" tab you can see the contract code, but also the contract name which is "GnosisSafeProxy"

This is not here that you will find the contract code, this is a proxy that links to the actual contract. If you go the the "Read as a Proxy" tab, you will finally find the contract :

> ABI for the implementation contract at [0xd9db270c1b5e3bd161e8c8503c55ceabee709552](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd9db270c1b5e3bd161e8c8503c55ceabee709552#code), likely using a custom proxy implementation.

And then search for the function you want details on.

---

For the record, this could has been a bit faster using a really useful tool : https://github.com/dethcrypto/dethcode

If you replace the `.io` in the link by `deth.net`, you will have a VScode interface to explore the contract : https://etherscan.deth.net/address/0x28257e0ae6ac7a31fbfb19aaf29a17122af89b5c#readProxyContract
The tool will bypass the proxy and show you the contract code